# After update glibc to version 2.34 , sem_open() failed: sem_open fail: Read-only file system

Tags: c++, linux, glibc, libc++

I am trying to update glibc to 2.34 for my system, then I came across the issue.

Test code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (2 != argc)
    {
        printf("%s name\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    
    int flags = O_CREAT;
    const char* _name = argv[1];
    sem_t* _newsem = sem_open(_name, flags, 0666, 0);
    if (SEM_FAILED == _newsem)
    {
        perror("sem_open fail");
        return -1;
    }
    
    sem_close(_newsem);
    return 0;
}
```

Run:

```
# ./a.out /tmp
sem_open fail: Read-only file system
```

I have known that the glibc-2.34 have some changes on sem_open(): https://lwn.net/Articles/864920/

but I have no idea to fix the issue? If you have any suggestions ，pls help me.

Comment: Check if /dev/shm is mounted read-write and has the correct permissions (drwxrwxrwt and owned by root:root).

Comment: Hi, David. I have change /dev/shm permissions to 1777 ,but it does't work.    `# ./a.out /tmp
sem_open fail: Read-only file system
# ./a.out /dev/shm
sem_open fail: Invalid argument
# ls -l /dev | grep shm
drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root             3 Dec 27 06:54 shm
#
`

Comment: And are you running as root user? If not, does it not even work when you are a root user?

Comment: Yes, I am the root user.  `# mkdir mypermission
# ls -lrt ./ | grep  mypermission
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            40 Dec 28 23:59 mypermission
#`

Comment: Do `strace ./a.out /tmp` and look for a line that begins `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/shm/sem.tmp", ...` and show us that line.

Comment: openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/shm/sem.tmp", O_RDWR|O_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: @Mr.Zhang Oh, that's the wrong one. Look for another one that has O_CREAT in the flags.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz,  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/shm/sem.FYbgmL", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666) = -1 EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: And you are sure that `/dev/shm` is not mounted read only? What does `cat /proc/mounts | grep /dev/shm` show?

Comment: `# cat /proc/mounts | grep /dev/shm
#
`

Comment: Oops, looks like `/dev/shm` is not mounted! *There's* your problem.

Comment: Hi, David. I have add `/dev/shm    /abc   tmpfs   defaults    0   0` to /etc/fstab, and `
# ls -l /dev | grep shm
drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root             3 Dec 29 03:46 shm
# cat /proc/mounts | grep shm
/dev/shm /abc tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
#
`  but `# ./strace ./a.out /tmp` still shows `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/shm/sem.vULXax", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666) = -1 EROFS (Read-only file system)`